# How do I get a King's Frill?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

The first time I killed a Great Jaggi, I got an item from it called King's Frill. Since then, I have killed about 10 more Great Jaggies and never seen another one. Do I need to do something special to get it to drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a  [King's Frill](http://kiranico.com/item/kings-frill) you need to break the head of the Great Jaggi. Just keep attacking his head and eventually you'll hear a breaking sound and animation, and his frill will get holes in it. At the end of the quest you'll then have a  65% chance to get a King's Frill. If you've already been doing that and still haven't gotten one then you're just experiencing bad luck, keep at it and you'll eventually get some frills.

It's also available as a quest reward from certain quests, the earliest of which is available in the 4-Star village quest [Hunter Killer](http://kiranico.com/quest/v4/hunter-killer).

Comment: Keyword turned out to be "at the end of the quest". I was ripping his head things correctly but since I was doing it on the jaggies in the forest it did not give me the frill.

Comment: You can report to Junior after going to Moga Woods and receive the item too. Just talk to him and select Hunt Report.

Comment: @Spidey I still have never had that happen and I've killed over 40 great jaggies in the woods by now. I think the difference may be that Junior will give you the star items and quests will give you the rare drops like the frill.